# Pandas sort_value not sorting properly

Tags: python, pandas

i'm getting a problem when trying to sort a column of numbers from 0-100 desc.

```
df_score = df.sort_values('score', ascending = False)
```

original dataframe is df:
[original df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOxlZ.png)

and the sorted df:
[sorted df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqEFW.png)

The sorted dataframe has been sorted correctly except for the last two rows, which are 100 both. They should be at the top two entries.

How do i resolve this? thanks

EDIT: The column was not in numeric form, which caused the error. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like your scores are being sorted as strings and not as numbers.

Comment: Convert to a numeric with `df['score'] = pd.to_numeric(df['score'])` before sorting so that it fixes the problem @JustinEzequiel raised

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, just did it now and worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, it looks like your score data are `str` and not numeric. This will cause them to be sorted in a somewhat alphabetical sense, rather than by value.  Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

nums = [2, 10, 5, 3, 1]
strs = [str(i) for i in nums]

df_num = pd.DataFrame(nums, columns = ['score'])
df_str = pd.DataFrame(strs, columns = ['score'])
```

Both of these "look like" this:

```
   score
0      2
1     10
2      5
3      3
4      1
```

But only the numeric one sorts as you expect:

```
df_num.sort_values('score', ascending = False)

Out[13]: 
   score
1     10
2      5
3      3
0      2
4      1
```

```
df_str.sort_values('score', ascending=False)

Out[15]: 
  score
2     5
3     3
0     2
1    10
4     1
```

As ALollz said, you can convert to numeric to fix:

```
df_str['score'] = pd.to_numeric(df_str['score']) #now the sort works
```

Answer (score 0):

***You are likely passing STRINGs instead of INTs.***

In which case, check the comments on your original question, where another user provided the following solution to easily convert those values to Integers:

`df_str['score'] = pd.to_numeric(df_str['score'])`

then

`df_score = df.sort_values('score', ascending = False)`

---

Assuming you intended to use Strings:
Sort can be funny in many different scenarios across different languages. What's happening here is that the sort function is counting the 2 digit scores as being sorted before the 3 digit scores. For example, if you had the following scores:

- 98
- 999
- 97
- 1000
- 120
- 998
- 4
- 9

Your sorting output would probably look like this:

- 9
- 4
- 98
- 97
- 999
- 998
- 120
- 1000

You can check [the documentation for sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Comment: This is the better-explained of the two answers and covers all possible issues. This should be the accepted answer.